# Always alive service even after boot completed

Tags: java, android, service

I want to run an Android service for a long time but i don't know how to fix it in my code, could you please advise?

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can [**help with certain problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [**put some efforts**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [**(re)search**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KlC2WdDPCKzT8gfFz72QDw). Read [**how to ask perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:stopWithTask="false"` in service under manifest as below. By using this if you remove app from task list, your service will not stop.

```
<service android:name=".service.StickyService"
     android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```